# How to add multiple sub domains for a single app in heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am working on a Ruby On Rails app, it has multiple sub-domains for example: "admin.example.com", "user.example.com", "members.example.com" , so my question is how to deploy my app so that all these sub-domains work in staging mode in heroku. It is working fine on local host (using lvh.me to access subdomains). Right now I am not using any custom domain , I am using default domain name provided by Heroku.

Answer (score 2):

Heroku has a free add-on that you can use to enable custom domain (and subdomain) names on their platform.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

If you read that support article, you'll see that you need to follow these steps:

1. Verify your account on Heroku by adding a credit card number - they won't charge anything for this particular add-on.
2. Run this command at your command line to add the domain name example1.com to your account, so Heroku knows to route inbound traffic using that domain to your app:

   ```
   $ heroku domains:add example1.com
   ```
3. Run this command to route all sub-domains of example1.com to your app:

   ```
   $ heroku domains:add *.example1.com
   ```

The tricky part may be configuring your domain name to route traffic to Heroku in the first place.  You'd do that by going to your domain name registrar, and creating a CNAME record in your DNS setup to route all traffic on *.example1.com to the original URL for your app on Heroku - example1.herokuapp.com.

Comment: my main app is pointing to admin.herokuapp.com , if i try to add new subdomain member.herokuapp.com it says  "Can't add an additional Heroku domain"

Comment: You can't have multiple (subdomain).herokuapp.com subdomains on a single app - this functionality is intended for use with your domain, aswal.com (or whatever you choose).  You can then follow the instructions above and direct traffic to your app for any subdomain of YOUR domain name, not Heroku's.  See what I mean?